# AngularJS - Check if an input of type "number" has a value, 0 being a valid value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling to get AngularJS to work properly with a small thing that I am trying to implement.

I have an input of type `number` (which likely causes the issue) which is bound to a variable in my controller, and I need to disable a button if this input is empty.

Here's the code for my input and button:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="20" ng-model="student.mark">

<button ng-disabled="!student">Send</button>
```

I tried several solutions to disable my button if the field is empty, but enable it if it has a value of `0`:

```
<button ng-disabled="!student || !student.mark">Send</button>

<button ng-disabled="!student || !angular.isNumber(student.mark)">Send</button>

<button ng-disabled="!student || student.mark == ''">Send</button>

<button ng-disabled="!student || student.mark === ''">Send</button>
```

None of those seem to work. It will work properly if I have any number in my input, but either the button will be disabled if I have the value "0", or the button will stay enabled if I put a valid value and then remove it.

What makes me think that it should work is the fact that if I display the value using `{{ student.mark }}`, the value `0` will indeed show as "0" and an empty input will show as empty.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you have more logic behind the scenes, but it works if you have just `ng-disabled="!student.mark"` (maybe you need `&&` instead of `||`)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey With this solution the button is disabled when the value of the field is "0" while it should be enabled.

Comment: Put a required attribute on the input?

Comment: @Endless Yeah but it won't disable my button.

Comment: IMHO i think disabling a submit btn is a bad practice. Having a good constrain validation on the form gives meningsfull errors to the form, you don't get them if you can't click the submit btn

Comment: @Endless I agree and I usually do it as you said, but in this particular case I thought it'd be more fitting like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few more things and actually testing if the value is `null` did the trick:

```
<button ng-disabled="!student || student.mark === null">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE :  0 is treated as false.

In your controller define

```
 $scope.student.mark = null;
```

Use condition

```
 ng-disabled="student.mark == null && student.mark < 0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use form for that, something like that:

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="someMethod(student)" autocomplete="off" 
novalidate>

<input type="number" min="0" max="20"
    ng-model="student.mark" placeholder="e.g. 12"
    ng-required="true" /> 
<button type="submit" value="Send" ng-disabled="formName.$invalid || <something else here>" />
</form>
```

Comment: I cannot really apply that solution as I have a form (without the form tag) in each row of a table, which makes it not valid HTML if I add the form tag. Not great but yeah...

Comment: bummer :/, I usually prefer to use form in this cases. maybe next time it will helps you :)